# Directory.GetFiles alters string path

Tags: c#

Using System.IO, I tried the following code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("\\folder\\folder_2\\folder_3");
```

And got the following exception:

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException - It was not possible to locate part of the path 'C:\folder\folder_2\folder_3)' "

I don't know why "c:\" was added to the original string, and I can't seem to keep the method from doing so. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: \ at the start of the path means the "go back to the root". Remove the first \ if you want a relative path.

Comment: `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"folder\folder_2\folder_3");`

Comment: Are you expecting the path to be relative to your currnet location od a raw UNC path (e.g. `\\SERVER\SHARE\folder_1\folder_2`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape each of the beginning backslashes in your path, you only escaped a single slash. Use either correct escaping:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\folder\\folder_2\\folder_3");
```

Or you can use a verbatim string literal:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\folder\folder_2\folder_3");
```

Full explanation found in [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A backslash (`\`) at the start of a path makes it an absolute path. Remove the first `\` if you want a relative path:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("folder\\folder_2\\folder_3");
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers provided, you could use **verbatim string literals**, which will pass the string exactly without the need for escaping with all the messy backslashes.

In your case this would be

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"folder\folder_2\folder_3");
```

Notice that the @ is outside of quotes, but stuck to the opening quotes, this tells C# to use it, (pardon the pun) literally. The syntax highlighting for this kind of string will also change in Visual Studio, just FYI.

edit: saw a comment by another user advising you to use the @, it's the same thing. Sorry did not see this earlier.

[Read about them here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It's called a "verbatim string literal", as opposed to regular string literals (without the @). Also, you left the leading backslash on :)